# Is there a way to get the file type with the magic bytes without using file command

Tags: python, windows, file, byte, mime-types

I'm trying to get the MIME type of a file in python on Windows. The purpose is to do it automatically, and if possible, without third-party software. I need to get the type with the magic bytes because its more reliable than the extension name of the file.

- Powershell does not determine file type with magic bytes, but with the file extension
- mimetypes library determine the MIME type with the file extension
- magic library is using the file command, only avaible on Unix

I guess the ultimate solution would be : reading the first bytes of the file, then check if it contains a magic byte signature. Is there a way to do what I want without reimplementing it ?

Comment: What's all this "magic bytes" stuff? Most file types **don't** have a signature, if that's what you mean. Your best bet is file extension or some OS-specifc meta-data.

Comment: It would be used for common file (png, jpg, pdf, docx, zip ...) which have a signature. I don't really need (at least now) to do it for other kind of file.

Comment: If it's data in the file, then it will have to be read and all the different signatures checked. With luck you may be able to find a Python module somewhere that does that for some or all the types of file types you're interested in (on multiple OSs), otherwise you'll need to implement it yourself. Also note that some signatures are at the end of the file.

Comment: Windows does have magic byte sniffing. It is a Internet Explorer related API IIRC. The byte mappings are stored in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

The [puremagic](https://github.com/cdgriffith/puremagic) package looks like the best cross-platform option. There is also [filetype.py](https://github.com/h2non/filetype.py/) but it doesn't support nearly as many as puremagic does:

https://github.com/cdgriffith/puremagic/blob/master/puremagic/magic_data.json

This is how I would use it:

```
import puremagic

mimetype = None
if p.is_dir():
    mimetype = "directory"
try:
    mimetype = puremagic.from_file(path, mime=True) or None
except Exception:
    if p.is_socket():
        mimetype = "socket"
    elif p.is_fifo():
        mimetype = "fifo"
    elif p.is_symlink():
        mimetype = "symlink"
    elif p.is_block_device():
        mimetype = "block device"
    elif p.is_char_device():
        mimetype = "char device"
```